# First app with JS in OOP

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I've already started to creating apps in JS with OOP.
I made simple TicTacToe Game in OOP and I want to ask you to review my code and point out everything that I can change about OOP. What is bad practice and what should I pay attention for?
Thank you!

````js
class Game {
    constructor(figures, boxes) {
        this.firstPlayer = '';
        this.buttons = figures;
        this.boxes = boxes;
        this.winingCombinations=[
            [0, 1, 2],
            [3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, 8],
            [0, 3, 6],
            [1, 4, 7],
            [2, 5, 8],
            [0, 4, 8],
            [2, 4, 6]
        ];
        this.arrO = [];
        this.arrX = [];
    }

    disableButtons(){
        this.buttons.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.classList.add('disactive');
        })
    }

    drawFigure(e){
        e.innerHTML = `<span>${this.firstPlayer}</span>`;
    }
    
    disableBox(e){
        e.classList.add('placeholder-disactive');
    }

    showPopup(winner){
        let popup = document.querySelector('.bg');
        if(winner === "Remis"){
            popup.querySelector('.winner-is').innerHTML=winner;
        } else {
            popup.querySelector('.winner-is').innerHTML="Wygrywa: " + winner;
        }
        popup.classList.add('bg-active');
    }
    
    toggleFigure(){
        if(this.firstPlayer === "O"){
            this.firstPlayer = "X";
        } else {
            this.firstPlayer = "O";
        }this.firstPlayer
        return this.firstPlayer;
    }

    addToArr(target,label){
        let arr = eval('this.arr' + this.firstPlayer);
        arr.push(target.getAttribute('data-number')*1);
        this.checkArr(arr,this.firstPlayer,label);
    }
    
    checkArr(arr,winner){
        let allFounded = false;
        if(arr.length >= 3){
            for(let i = 0;i < this.winingCombinations.length; i++){
                allFounded = this.winingCombinations[i].every( ai => arr.includes(ai));
                if(allFounded === true){
                    this.endOfGame(this.winingCombinations[i],winner);
                    return;
                }
                 else if(arr.length === 5 && allFounded === false){
                    console.log('draw');
                    this.endOfGame([],'Remis');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    endOfGame(winnerSet,winner){
        this.boxes.forEach((box) => {
            box.classList.add('endGame');
            box.classList.add('placeholder-disactive');
            for(let i = 0; i < winnerSet.length; i++){
                box.getAttribute('data-number')*1 == winnerSet[i] ? box.classList.add('win') : 0;

            }
        })
        this.showPopup(winner);
    }

    setStartPlayer(player = this.firstPlayer) {
        this.firstPlayer = player;
        document.querySelector('.select__player .player').innerHTML = player;
    }

    disablePopup(){
        document.querySelector('.bg').classList.remove('bg-active');
    }

    activeBoxes(action){
        this.boxes.forEach((box) => {
            eval(`box.classList.${action}('placeholder-disactive')`);
        })
    }

    activeBtns(){
        this.buttons.forEach((figure) => {
            figure.classList.remove('disactive');
        })
    }
    clearArrays(){
        this.arrO = [];
        this.arrX = [];
    }

    clearBoxes(){
        this.boxes.forEach((box) => {
            box.innerHTML = '';
            box.className = 'placeholder';
        })
    }

    reset(){
        this.disablePopup();
        this.clearBoxes();
        this.activeBtns();
        this.clearArrays();
        this.setStartPlayer('');
    }

    boxHandle(event){
        const label = document.querySelector('.select__player .text');
        label.innerHTML = 'Tura gracza: ';
        this.drawFigure(event.target);
        this.disableBox(event.target);
        this.addToArr(event.target,label);
        this.toggleFigure();
        this.setStartPlayer();
    }

    popupHandle(event){
        if(event.getAttribute('data-answear') == "Tak"){
            this.reset();
            this.activeBoxes('add');
        } else {
            this.disablePopup();
        }
    }

    init() {;
        this.boxes.forEach((box) => {
            box.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                this.boxHandle(event);
            })
        })
        this.buttons.forEach((button) => {
            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                this.firstPlayer = button.innerHTML;
                this.setStartPlayer();
                this.disableButtons();
                this.activeBoxes('remove');
            })
        })
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    const figures = document.querySelectorAll('.select__box');
    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.placeholder');
    const popup = document.querySelector('.btns');
    newGame = new Game (figures, boxes);
    newGame.init();
    popup.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        newGame.popupHandle(e.target);
    })
    
})
```
````

Answer (score 5):

### Few review points.

- Messy formating, inconsistent use of spacing, newlines, and some poor indentation.

  ```
  if(...){                     // use spaces. eg if ( ) {
  }
  else if(                    // same line as closing }. eg } else if (

  ('...number')*1              // space between operators. eg ('...number') * 1

  endGame(winSet,wins){        // spaces. eg endGame(winSet, wins) {
  ```
- Use modern JS

  Example from your code

  ```
  for(let i = 0; i < winnerSet.length; i++){
    box.getAttribute('data-number')*1 == winnerSet[i] ? box.classList.add('win') : 0;
  }
  ```

  Can be written as

  ```
  for (const idx of winnerSet) {
    box.dataset.number == idx && box.classList.add("win");
  }
  ```
- Why need the second required call to `Game.init()` outside the object `Game`? Better to do that in the constructor.
- Define constants associated with the Object as static. Eg

  ```
  class Game {
    static winingCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], .... ];
  ```

  Accessible via `Game.winingCombinations`

  Note that it can not easily be made constant using class syntax.
- There is no state protection using private properties or functions.

  Using class syntax you can create private members using the prescript `#` for example.

  ```
  class Game {
    static #winingCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], .... ];
  ```

  Accessible only from within the class via `Game.#winingCombinations`

  Almost all properties and function should be private. This ensures that your code can trust the integrity of the objects state.

### [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Your object `Game` can (and as your example shows) be a singleton.

Your Game can ONLY be instantiated once, creating a second `Game` object would interfere with the existing instances.

The [class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) may not be the best option in this case.

#### Defining Objects.

The [class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) is not the only way to define `Object`s in JS.

Your `Game` object would be much better suited to a [object factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) like [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) totally eliminating the need to fill the code with `this.` (51 times in 150 lines of your code, that a lot of code noise).

An IIFE that uses closure to encapsulate state can totally trust its state. No outside code has access or can make changes.

It can't be accidentally instanced more than once. As an IIFE in the global scope it will only ever be instantiated once

Comment: thumbs up for IIFE suggestion. Class syntax is just "syntax sugar" anyway (i.e. JS does not have classes, only objects) and does not deter the brain dump linear stream of consciousness that is typical JS coding. Oh, Objects. Wherefore art thou?

Comment: Thank you very much for such an comprehensive reply. I have read a little about IIFE and will also try to make a simple game like hangman using IIFE and will share the code here. I thought that you should use new class syntax due to the fact that it is new, but I see now that I should learn in which cases what syntax to use. Do you know any good site or repository that describes when to use available objects?

Comment: @SzymonMińko The links in my answer link to MDN which has a comprehensive web related references, tutorials, and links.

Answer (score 0):

Just some tips: if you want to execute your code after the DOM content has loaded you can use the `defer` attribute. Then you can put all your logic in the game class instead of in the `DOMContentLoaded` handler:

```html
<script defer src="mygame.js"></script>
```

You have coded one single huge class, which kind of defeats the purpose of OOP. You could think about creating a separate class to draw the Game Board. In this example I show the "domcontentloaded" code and the board class:

```
class Game() {

   board
   figures
   boxes
   popup

   constructor() {
      this.figures = document.querySelectorAll('.select__box');
      this.boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.placeholder');
      this.popup = document.querySelector('.btns');
      this.popup.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.popupHandle(e.target))

      this.board = new Board()
      this.init()
   }

   init() {
   }

   popupHandle(target){
   }

   stateWasChanged() {
      this.board.updateState()
   }
}

class Board() {
   updateState() {
       console.log("draw the board")
   }
}

new Game()
```